# How to import mysql database (schema.sql) in OpenShift v3 with mysql datastore?

Tags: mysql, openshift

Before I'm using OpenShift v2 and it is quite easy to import the mysql schema to the app. I'll just add a phpMyadmin cartridges to my OpenShift app and then import my sql file. But now in OpenShift v3 they don't have a phpMyadmin cartridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to migrate MySQL database applications from OpenShift version 2 (v2) to OpenShift version 3 (v3). If so, here are the steps:

Export all databases to a dump file and copy it to a local machine (into the current directory):

```
$ rhc ssh <v2_application_name>
$ mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -P ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT:-3306} -u ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:-'admin'} \
 --password="$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD" --all-databases > ~/app-root/data/all.sql
$ exit
```

Download dbdump to your local machine:

```
$ mkdir mysqldumpdir
$ rhc scp -a <v2_application_name> download mysqldumpdir app-root/data/all.sql
```

Create a v3 mysql-persistent pod from template:

```
$ oc new-app mysql-persistent -p \
   MYSQL_USER=<your_V2_mysql_username> -p \
   MYSQL_PASSWORD=<your_v2_mysql_password> -p MYSQL_DATABASE=<your_v2_database_name>
```

Check to see if the pod is ready to use:

```
$ oc get pods
When the pod is up and running, copy database archive files to your v3 MySQL pod:

$ oc rsync /local/mysqldumpdir <mysql_pod_name>:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

Restore the database in the v3 running pod:

```
$ oc rsh <mysql_pod>
$ cd /var/lib/mysql/data/mysqldumpdir
```

In v3, to restore databases you need to access MySQL as root user.

In v2, the $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME had full privileges on all databases. In v3, you must grant privileges to $MYSQL_USER for each database.

```
$ mysql -u root
$ source all.sql
Grant all privileges on <dbname> to <your_v2_username>@localhost, then flush privileges.
```

Remove the dump directory from the pod:

```
$ cd ../; rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/data/mysqldumpdir
```

Comment: An alternative to needing to upload the data dump file into the container is to use port forwarding to expose the database to your local machine. You can then use the ``mysql`` client on your local box to connect to the remote database and replay the data dump. See the scenario at https://learn.openshift.com/ on port forwarding. It shows an example of connecting to a remote database that way using PostgreSQL. Same idea for MySQL.